# implementation of UML generalization constraints

Tags: c++, uml

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class User {
    string name;
    public:
    User(string x):name(x)
    {   }
    void print() {
        cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
    }
};

class Director : public User
{
public:
    Director(string x) : User(x)
    {}
};
class Seller : public User
{
public:
    Seller(string x) : User(x)
    {   }
};
class Admin : public User
{
public:
    Admin(string x) : User(x)
    {   }
};

int main() {

    User x("A");
    Director z("B");
    x.print();
    z.print();
}
```

How using this class hierarchy can I present that classes:
Director, Admin, Seller are:

-complete, disjoint (I guess it's the sample of code I have given)

-incomplete, disjoint (will it be the same?)

-complete, overlapping

-incomplete, overlapping

Comment: Read your lecture. If the script isn't nice, talk to your tutor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class hierarchy must be represented by Generalization Set element of UML.
Disjoint and incomplete are attributes of this element.